# Interaction with an option element through the webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

Html code:

```
<span id="syi-attribute-1277" class="dropdown l-stretchable-fixed native" tabindex="7146">

<input type="hidden" value="" name="attribute[1277]"></input>
<span class="label" style=""></span>
<span class="pointer"></span>
<select class="item-frame" size="1" style="height: 30px; width: 264px;">
    <option class="item" value=""></option>
    <option class="item" value="7146"></option>
    <option class="item" value="7147"></option>
    <option class="item" value="7148"></option>
</select>
```

What I'd like to do is the webbrowser control in my form (using WinForms) be able to select the third option of this drop down selection list (with the value of 7148). What I've tried so far:

```
doc.GetElementById("syi-attribute-1277").Children.GetElementsByName("option")[0].SetAttribute("value", "7148");
```

^ makes the most sense, though sadly it gives me this error: Additional information: Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.

Code:

```
doc.GetElementById("syi-attribute-1277").SetAttribute("tabindex", "7148");
```

^ Nothing happens.

Any clue's? Thanks. :-)

Comment: Where is the element with id `syi-attribute-1277` ?

Comment: <span id="syi-attribute-1277" class="dropdown l-stretchable-fixed native" tabindex="7146"> There it is! I made a mistake formatting this post. Sorry!

Comment: Can you try this? doc.getElementsByClassName("option")[0].SetAttribute("value", "7148");

Comment: @Eplzong "Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'getElementsByClassName' and no extension method 'getElementsByClassName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Ok. try to catch them with doc.GetElementsByTagName("option")[0].SetAttribute("value", "7148");

Comment: @Eplzong Getting the same error with the first example I used: "Additional information: Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.", out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

`GetElementsByName` looks for a matching `name` (or `id`) attribute, not the element name.

Your also trying to set the value attribute on the `option`, you need to use the `select` if you want to set the value:

```
doc.GetElementById("syi-attribute-1277").GetElementsByTagName("select")[0].SetAttribute("value", "7148");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried this, but I still get this as error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.

Comment: It works for me using http://jsbin.com/bekeqozuma/1/ - You are waiting for the document to fully load?

Comment: Yep, I even added a timer with a delay of 4 seconds to make 100% sure the document has been fully loaded. Still got the exception.